# Style the vertical tab indents in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, themes

I'm working on a theme for Visual Studio Code. Using the developer tools I can see there are elements with a class of "cigr". I do I style their color? There isn't any information on the Website about how to override the default style for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
"editorIndentGuide.background": "#ff0000"
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors